# create a search bar jsvue from json object

Tags: json, image, video, vue.js, axios

I want to create a search bar that pulls searches through the data of a json object and displays data to the user. I currently have code that looks like this and it works fine.

```
<html>


<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> </head>   <body> <div id='app'>   <input type='text' v-model='keyword' placeholder='search title'>   <button v-on:click="">automotive</button>   <div v-for="post in filteredList"> <iframe width="420" height="315" v-bind:src="post.link">   </iframe>  <a v-bind:href="post.link">{{post.title}}</a>   </div>   </div>
      <script> "use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Post = function Post(title, link, author, img) {  
_classCallCheck(this, Post);

  this.title = title;   this.link = link;   this.author = author;   this.img = img; }; var app = new Vue({   el: '#app',   data: {
    keyword:'',
    postList: [
      new Post(
        'Vue.js', 
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY', 
        'Chris', 
        'https://vuejs.org//images/logo.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'React.js', 
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/k3frK9-OiQ0', 
        'Tim',
        'http://daynin.github.io/clojurescript-presentation/img/react-logo.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Angular.js', 
        'https://angularjs.org/', 
        'Sam', 
        'https://angularjs.org/img/ng-logo.png',
      ),
      new Post(
        'Ember.js', 
        'http://emberjs.com/', 
        'Rachel',
        'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0cf15665a9146ba852bf042b0652780a?s=200'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Meteor.js', 
        'https://www.meteor.com/', 
        'Chris', 
        'http://hacktivist.in/introduction-to-nodejs-mongodb-meteor/img/meteor.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Aurelia', 
        'http://aurelia.io/', 
        'Tim',
        'https://cdn.auth0.com/blog/aurelia-logo.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Node.js', 
        'https://nodejs.org/en/', 
        'A. A. Ron',
        'https://code-maven.com/img/node.png'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Pusher', 
        'https://pusher.com/', 
        'Alex', 
        'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/739550?v=3&s=400'
      ),
      new Post(
        'Feathers.js', 
        'http://feathersjs.com/', 
        'Chuck',
        'https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/feathersjs.svg'
      ), ]   },   methods: {
       },   computed:{
    filteredList(){
      return this.postList.filter((post) => {
        return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
    }   } })
      </script>   </body>   <html>
```

Ignore what the links are going to it doesnt matter. The problem Im having however is getting this to work from an external source via an axios request. I've done axios request before and got json data back but im struggling to make this search feature work with it. The following is an example of the broken code (ignore the v-on:click its not set up yet. ignore the fact there are no videos I can deal with that later I just need the search feature to work with an json data from an axios request) but I keep getting errors like 'type error : this.item is not defined' and 'object error' anyway heres the code:

```
<html>


 <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id='app'>
  <input type='text' v-model='keyword' placeholder='search item'>
  <button v-on:click="">automotive</button>
  <div v-for="item in filteredList">

<p>{{item.name}}</p>
  </div>
  </div>
      <script>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keyword:'',
    itemList: '',

  },
             created: function() {
            this.loaddata();
            },
            methods: {
                loaddata: function(){
                  var vueapp = this;
                    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(function (response){
                        vueapp.itemList = response.data;
                    })
                },
            },

  computed:{
    filteredList(){
      return this.item.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }
})
      </script>
  </body>
  <html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `item` declared in your data. you can't call `this.item.filter` in your `filteredList()` method when you don't have it declared.

You can change your `filteredList`  with `this.itemList.filter()` which is the list being loaded in `loaddata()`